# Xamarin.Forms: How to Give Highlight Color to Label On Tap?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I know that I can make a `Label` clickable by using `TapGesture`. How can I give a highlight effect when the user is **tapping** it? (Either changing the Label's color or changing the Background Color just like when the user taps the Toolbar Items)

Comment: Sounds like it would be better to use a button. You can create a 'flat button style' so it will appear like a label, but still have the background animation effect when clicked.

Comment: @sme I did that, but I need the highlight effect to appear on the other tappable controls I have like StackLayout and Images. I need something like `OnTapping` method where I can just change the color property

Answer (score 1):

You could simulate the effect with a `TapGestureRecognizer` by just changing the color of your label in your tapped method and back at the end.

```
private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = sender as Label;
    label.TextColor = Color.Gray;
    //Do Something
    label.TextColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Although, styling a button might work better to handle the effect for you.

Comment: To make it work, you'll have to do this on main ui thread which is definitely undesirable - since while the application is doing your 'something' it will not respond to any events. I agree with @sme that using a button instead of a label is the easiest solution.

Comment: It really depends on what your something is and what exactly he's trying to achieve with the effect. You could still do an async task there the thing is if he awaits it though the color wouldn't change back until after the task finishes.

Comment: I don't think you can, since OnTapped function is not async. Bottomline - Michael, use button and style it as label.

Comment: Obviously, you'd add the async modifier and I mentioned styling a button might be better for him. The only problem with styling the button is on Android it's not as simple as having a button with a transparent background because depending on the version of Android it will still have a border, which to get around you'd have to make [an effect or renderer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63850/android-button-how-to-make-transparent-background-and-no-border).

Comment: @Grisha I would actually need the solution instead of rendering a custom button because I would need the highlight effects on my tappable images and stacklayouts as well.

Comment: StackLayout is not a control. You can't tap it. Image can be placed in button. Probably you can achieve what you want without buttons - you can use absolute layout and put the colored image temporarily under your control and then remove it. But it's a LOT of work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix to [Nick Pepper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503459/199364), to properly restore color on UI thread.

```
private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = sender as Label;
    label.TextColor = Color.Gray;
    Run.Task( () => {
        // Now we are on a background thread, can take as long as we want.
        // ... Do Something ...
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
            // Now we are back on main thread, can change UI.
            label.TextColor = Color.Black;
        });
    });
}
```

HOWEVER this won't change color to Gray until OnTapped fires - which is NOT the instant that user pushes down. So still isn't what user asked for.

Changing the color as soon as the user starts pushing is more involved. Might need to use [Touch Tracking API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking#the-touch-tracking-effect-api).

OR use [Visual State Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager).